# Swift Collision Not Working After SKReferenceNode Scale

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a weird problem where my SKReferenceNode does not collide properly after being scaled up. It collides well in the center, but it ignores collisions and contacts on the edges.

[Here is the first photo of the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqDaJ.png). The SKReferenceNode was scaled up significantly, and as seen in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ0ZJ.jpg) photo, does not collide correctly on the edges. The PhysicsBody appears to be correct (with showPhysics on), yet the ball refuses to collide.

The SKReferenceNode is using an alpha collision mask, because I need to change it to a larger sprite in the future to do animations and such. Additionally, non-scaled objects work completely fine. Finally, after the ball collides with the center, which does work, and the block is reset, collisions start working as expected again. The code to fix it is probably in the reset function, but I reset everything before the level is loaded, so this wouldn't make sense. Here is a part of my reset code:

```
func reset() {
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -9.8)
    for grav in gravityBlock {
        grav.reset()
    }

    gravity = -9.8

    //Resets blocks
    for blocks in destroyedBlocks { //the blocks are stored in destroyedBlocks when collided with
        blocks.reset()
    }

    destroyedBlocks = []

    /*Irrelevant code removed*/
    }
```

Here's my blocks.reset() function:

```
    override func reset() {
    super.reset()

    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
    removeAllActions()

    self.texture = self.text
    shadow.hidden = false

    self.alpha = 0
    shadow.alpha = 0

    let appear = SKAction(named: "Appear")!
    self.runAction(appear)
    shadow.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.25))
}
```

Here is super.reset()

```
    func reset() {
    self.hidden = false
    state = .NotBroken
}
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

When you scale the sprite you are just changing it's visual representation. The Physics Body stays the same. That's why you are getting the "strange" during the collisions.

You can see that showing the physics uses in your scene, just open `GameViewController` and add this line

```
skView.showsPhysics = true
```

inside `viewDidLoad`, just after this line

```
skView.showsNodeCount = true
```

Then run again your game, the physics boundaries now will be highlighted.

Comment: I actually tried that already, [here](http://i.imgur.com/ZC40jam.png) is a link to a picture. The physicsBody covers the entire block, yet it still doesn't collide.